# async await @MainActor crash "Modifications to the layout engine must not be performed from a background thread"

Tags: swift, async-await, concurrency, grand-central-dispatch

I have a crash when trying to reload collectionView inside the method update() which marked as @MainActor. "Modifications to the layout engine must not be performed from a background thread after it has been accessed from the main thread"

I know, that you should update the UI from main thread only. Using GCD it works

```
private func update() {
      DispatchQueue.main.async {
          collectionView.reloadData()
      }
}
```

I thought that if you mark you method with @MainActor in async/await world, then this function will be executed in the main thread automatically. But it crashes.

```
extension PhotosCollectionViewController: PHPhotoLibraryChangeObserver {
    func photoLibraryDidChange(_ changeInstance: PHChange) {
        update()
    }
    
    @MainActor private func update() {
        collectionView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: `DispatchQueue.main.async` and `@MainActor` are two very different approaches. To use `async await`/`@MainActor` you have to convert `PHPhotoLibraryChangeObserver` to be `async await` and use an `AsyncStream` of sorts, it isn't a one line thing.

Comment: What about this one? Because this one is working
private func update() {
        Task {
            await MainActor.run {
                collectionView.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }

Comment: That is like using duct tape. You are needlessly creating a task just put it on a main thread. You might as well use GCD. To in true concurrency you would register, listen, and unregister in 1 function. You could even check for permission, request permission and then register-listen-unregister in a true linear fashion in a single function. `@MainActor` would ensure the main actor or updates and leave the thread for the rest.

Answer (score 0):

`@MainActor` only works when using Swift concurrency and ensures that when you are in an async context calling a `@MainActor` annotated function is executed on the main thread (actually the actor's executor which in this case is always the main queue).

In your example you call the function in a synchronous context which uses the same thread it was called from (as always).